# Problems with API Key Management (v1.3.5) extension?

Tags: extension, api, bug-reporting

When I go to API Key section, it does not provide any controls to add or remove keys, just two narrowish grey lines where key should be.

Is it a bug and how to fix it?

CiviCRM 5.53.0 on Drupal 7.

[image]